# How to read iptables TRACE logs (policy numbers)

Tags: iptables, trace, policy

So I added

`sudo iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 25 -j TRACE`

as well as

`sudo iptables -t raw -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -j TRACE`

and when I grep my syslog for TRACE I get output that looks like this

```
Jan 19 09:14:46 dev109 kernel: [29067248.683235] TRACE: raw:OUTPUT:rule:2 IN= OUT=eth0  ...
Jan 19 09:14:46 dev109 kernel: [29067248.683244] TRACE: raw:OUTPUT:policy:5 IN= OUT=eth0 ...
Jan 19 09:14:46 dev109 kernel: [29067248.683254] TRACE: mangle:OUTPUT:policy:1 IN= OUT=eth0 ...
Jan 19 09:14:46 dev109 kernel: [29067248.683262] TRACE: filter:OUTPUT:policy:1 ...
Jan 19 09:14:46 dev109 kernel: [29067248.683269] TRACE: mangle:POSTROUTING:policy:1 ...
Jan 19 09:14:46 dev109 kernel: [29067248.683432] TRACE: raw:OUTPUT:rule:4 IN= OUT=eth0 ...
Jan 19 09:14:46 dev109 kernel: [29067248.683441] TRACE: raw:OUTPUT:policy:5 IN= OUT=eth0 ...
```

I am trying to understand what the policy numbers refer to, is `policy:1` == `ACCEPT`?, if so what does `policy:5` mean?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`policy:1` is `type:rulenum`. Or put another way `type="policy"` and `rulenum=1`.

Read [this](http://backreference.org/2010/06/11/iptables-debugging/) carefully. Specifically:

> TRACE
>   This target marks packes so that the kernel will log every rule which match the packets as those traverse the tables, chains,
>   rules. (The ipt_LOG or ip6t_LOG module is required for the logging.) The packets are logged with the string prefix:
>
> "TRACE: tablename:chainname:type:rulenum " where type can be "rule" for plain rule, "return" for implicit rule at the end of a user
>   defined chain and "policy" for the policy of the built in chains.
>   It can only be used in the raw table.

Now let's take one of the prefixes from the question `TRACE: mangle:OUTPUT:policy:1` and apply what we've learned:

```
tablename = mangle
chainname = OUTPUT
type      = policy]
rulenum   = 1
```

Comment: This was a very terse answer, but it got me to where I needed to be after reading it a dozen time. I edited the answer to help better explain. That first sentence was hard to grasp when it was alone.

Comment: came to this question too and dit some testing:  **policy:5** seem to refer to the fictive last "rule" of your chain, where the policy is considered. so loonyuni's traced chain should have **4** explicit rules in it.

Comment: I fail to understand if the last fictive last rule 5 means it's accepted or dropped.

Comment: @Johnathan Isn't that the default policy then?

Comment: @U.Windl How would you determine that?

Comment: @internetdotcom You can see the default policy for each chain by printing out the chain with a command such as `iptables -L -t filter`. See my answer below for an example.

Answer (score 1):

I want to provide a simple explanation based off of the answer written by @OscarAkaElvis and others.

Every chain has a default policy, which can be seen if you print out rules. Here, we can see that the `INPUT` chain in the `filter` table has a default policy of `ACCEPT`:

```
# iptables -L -t filter
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             /* 000 accept all icmp */
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* 001 accept all to lo interface */
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             127.0.0.0/8          /* 002 reject local traffic not on loopback interface */ reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

As stated in https://backreference.org/2010/06/11/iptables-debugging/ , the format for the log message is `TRACE: tablename:chainname:type:rulenum`.

For Policies, the last part of the format is `type:rulenum`. The `rulenum` number is referring to the default rule for the policy, which is the last rule. It's basically "The number of rules that you added to the chain" + 1.

Here are two explanations using the chains put forth in the original question:

- `mangle:OUTPUT:policy:1` This chain (`mangle:OUTPUT`) contains no rules. The default rule is the first and only rule. Therefore the number is `:1`.
- `raw:OUTPUT:policy:5` This chain contains 4 rules. Therefore, the default is rule #5.